# Relative path to sub-directory in PHP and Apache's htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on my own PHP Framework. I am currently developing it on localhost and everything related to project is in subfolder called RuddyPhpFramework, so the path look like this:

localhost/RuddyPhpFramework/

In that folder, I do have index.php, the init point of whole Framework. I am currently working on my own router, but I have a two problems. First, in Apache's htaccess file a have this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) RuddyPhpFramework/index.php [L]
```

So whenever someone acces a page like this:

localhost/RuddyPhpFramework/something/smtelse/

The index.php will init the application and echo a path for me, which is:

```
[path] => /RuddyPhpFramework/something/smtelse/
```

But that is not excatly what I want. What I want is to get a relative path to subfolder (I don't know if I am explaining this correctly), for example:

```
[path] => /something/smtelse/
```

And another problem is that I want to setup the htacces so the last line would look something like this:

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]
```

So it will go for the index.php in the folder where is the htaccess file (/RuddyPhpFramework/index.php) and not /index.php, without specifying the foler, because if someone else will be using the framework, he might have it in a folder with different name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first please stop we have enouth frameworks already. Now regarding your question. Your project is in localhost/RuddyPhpFramework so htaccess read url from first / so he skips localhost because it's domain and taiks uri witch starts from /

so you project setup is incorrect. what you could try not shure 100%:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /RuddyPhpFramework/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]
```

please try it. and say did it helped.

Comment: This framework is only for my personal projects and educational purposes. I am not planing to release it widely, I just want to understand how other frameworks works inside and improve my PHP skill :) And yes, it works! Thanks